# Can we put the charts from the TFS web portal dashboard on to SharePoint TFS portal?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, reporting

There are nice charts on the TFS web portal. Can we place them on the TFS SharePoint portal?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant add the charts outside of the Web Access.